# Can't install a Earmaster 6.1

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm trying to install Earmaster 6.1 on Windows 7 x64. The setup is an exe file. I installed it but I wanted to do something first so I uninstalled it. But now I can't install it anymore, the setup runs but right after it starts: "The file is corrupted, please download it again from (...)". I've tried downloading the file again and from other sources but nothing seems to work. Other exe files are working. I ran ccleaner (not really sure why), disabled my antivirus completely, ran it in different compatibility modes and deleted the AppData/.../Earmaster folder but nothing worked. It must be something saved somewhere else, right?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Comment: @ekaj Yes, I just installed a new operating system on my pc and it still doesn't work. How is this possible? It worked once...

Comment: Try making sure that all of your other drivers are up to date first; Windows update and vendor-specific drivers from their website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the installation package currently available on the website. We are making a new build at the moment, so you can simply download it in a few hours and it will work.

Apologies for the inconvenience.

--
The EarMaster support team

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally did it, the firewall was the problem. I'm still trying it but it seems great. Good job! :)